# Command line code with php-fpm doenst give me the result like php

Tags: php, command-line-interface, fpm

I have a problem running code through php-fpm command line

when I run it with the normal php cli

```
php -r 'echo php_ini_scanned_files();'
```

it returns the result

but with

```
php-fpm -r 'echo php_ini_scanned_files();'
```

it does return how to use it, and i cant see anything like -r in the usage

Comment: FPM accepts input through a socket.